# afterSubmit not always fired

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid table displayed then I have some properties set with navGrid like so:

```
$("#opozorila").jqGrid('navGrid', '#opozorilapager',
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid},//Note: reloadGrid contains just alert('test');
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid},
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid});
```

This works great if I select row, click on edit **through navGrid menu** and submit edited row. But it doesn't work if I get to the edit popup like this:

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
        //var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#opozorila").jqGrid('editGridRow', id);
    },
```

Basically it only gets triggered if popup was open through navGrid menu. How can I make it work in both ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition) in a wrong way. You should add `{}` parameter after `'#opozorilapager'`:

```
$("#opozorila").jqGrid('navGrid', '#opozorilapager',
    {}, // !!! navGrid options
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid},//Note: reloadGrid contains just alert('test');
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid},
    {afterSubmit: reloadGrid});
```

Now about your main question. Callback `afterSubmit` is an option of `editGridRow` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events)) so you should specify it as a parameter if you call it explicitly:

```
onSelectRow: function(id) {
    $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', id, {afterSubmit: reloadGrid});
}
```

If you have multiple places where you call `editGridRow` I would recommend you to save options in a variable and use the variable in `navGrid` and at explicitly calling of `editGridRow`:

```
var paramEdit = { afterSubmit: reloadGrid },
    paramAdd = { afterSubmit: reloadGrid },
    paramDel = { afterSubmit: reloadGrid },
    $myGrid = $("#opozorila");

...
$myGrid.jqGrid({
    ...
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        $(this).jqGrid("editGridRow", rowid, paramEdit);
    }
});
$myGrid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#opozorilapager", {}, paramEdit, paramAdd, paramDel);
```

Comment: Now I have another problem, if I override afterSubmit, then it "popup" won't close after I click submit. Before this was done automatically but now I have to do it manually I guess, correct?

Comment: @user1188570: Sorry, but I ca't follow you. It would be easier if you post the code of `reloadGrid` function which you use. Typical error in the function - you don't return anything or you return wrong data. I posted in my answer [the link](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) to documentation which described the format of return data. One have to return array with up to 3 elements. The first boolean value is required: `return [true];` in case of error you can return error message: `return [false, "error description"]`.

Comment: @user1188570: In case of "Add" operation the server can generate new rowid and return it from the server inside of the response. So you can return the value of new id as the 3-d parameter of array returned from `afterSubmit`: `return [true, "", 1234];`. The callback functions `afterSubmit` of Edit and Delete returns always only array with one or two elements in the same format.